# VBA modules getting deleted from .xls files for one user but not another

Tags: excel, vba, module, excel-2007, excel-2016

I am automating a project for a user based in a different location.

The project in question includes inputting data into .xls files for the user and the user then runs  macros saved in these .xls files (They cannot be changed to .xlm).

I use excel 2016 and can open these files no problem. however the other user can only open them in excel 2007, when opened in 2016 the modules disappear. Anyone have any idea how I can solve this.

So Far I have compared both our setting's in excel, with no outcome. I am unsure where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: Just so we don,t go over already covered ground, can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53176159/edit) and let us know what you have done to debug this problem?

Comment: added, I have compared our excel settings

Comment: Why can't they be changed to .xlm? You're basically trying to use a 15 year old file format, in that the macro security enhancements beginning with 2007 attempt to avoid precisely this scenario.

Comment: I'd guess the other user doesn't have VBA installed in his 2016 installation.

Comment: @Comintern agreed but its a file which gets sent to a client so not our call